# How to find out if wandb is initialized?

Tags: python, machine-learning, wandb

At the start of my application, I initialize a connection to WeightsAndBiases via

```py
run = wandb.init(project="...")
```

Later on, I would like to check if a `wandb` run has been initialized.
Is there a way to do this without passing the `run` object around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The currently active run object can be accessed via `wandb.run`. It will be  `None` if no run is initialised.

```py
if wandb.run is not None:
    print("There is an active connection to wandb")
```

It is guaranteed that there is at most one active `wandb.Run` object in any process ([source](https://github.com/wandb/wandb/blob/fa4423647026d710e3780287b4bac2ee9494e92b/wandb/sdk/wandb_run.py#L443C1-L444C1)).

Comment: Covered also in https://github.com/wandb/wandb/issues/3551 (minus the "mostly one" part).